# VB to email from Draft folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2010

Quick question...

Had a a VB "app" in excel that takes an .oft file, adds  name to it from VB app in Excel, places in Outlook Draft.

Second piece of code, in Outlook, allows me to send the Draft folder emails based on duration and #, i.e., 3 emails every 2 minutes for example. Let's call it Send.

It was working fine..then I did something in Outlook or Windows. Now if the Send function is on, it does not send it anymore..it moves it from Draft to Outbox.

I need to get it back to where it was, sendinng from Draft. No, haven't touched the code at all..not a programmer.

Got to be some kind of configuration setting I changed in Outlook. HELP!

Chris